# Replace \[ ... \] and \( ... \) blocks in string by {0}, {1}, etc

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
"Some text \[(2 \cdot 3) = 6\] and more text and \((2^3) = 8\)" ...
```

How can I replace the `\[ ... \]` and `\( ... \)` blocks by `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, etc and place the removed blocks in a String Array?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: You should really look into making a real parser using something like antlr (http://antlr.net/)

Comment: I am already using a Markdown parser: http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/. I just want to remove and later add the formulas so they don't interfere with the parser as it is happening now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regex:

```
string input = @"Some text \[(2 \cdot 3) = 6\] and more text and \((2^3) = 8\)";
string pattern = @"\\\[.*\\\]|\\\(.*\\\)";
int index = 0;
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, 
                              match => string.Format("{{{0}}}", index++));
```

If you want to remember what text was replaced with which pattern, you can remember all matches:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\\\[.*\\\]|\\\(.*\\\)")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select((match, i) => new
                   {
                       Key = string.Format("{{{0}}}", i),
                       Text = match.Value
                   });
```

and them make a simple string replacement from one way or another:

```
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    input = input.Replace(match.Text, match.Key);
}
```

Comment: Konrad, how can I also place the removed strings into a string collection so later I can place them back into the string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes sense. You need to use *capture groups* and if you want to be extra careful, you need to make sure that the tokens you are using as a substitute (e.g. `{0}`) don't otherwise appear in the text you are processing.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy(v=vs.110).aspx for information on how to specify and reference the backreferences in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a pure-regex way to replace groups with an incremented value, but no doubt someone with better regex-fu than me will know.

A regex which finds groups enclosed in escaped square brackets or escaped parens might look like this:

```
(\\\[.*]|\\\(.*\))
```

http://rubular.com/r/uRePwMuWIV

Once you have the pattern, you should be able to use the Regex class to replace those groups incrementally.